# SQLAlchemy: How to select attributes from a polymorphic child without joining to its parent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a polymorphic class hierarchy:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    a_id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(255), nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'a',
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }


class B(A):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.a_id))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'b',
    }
```

I don't want `B` to be forced to join against `A` if I'm only retrieving an attribute from `B`, e.g.: `session.query(B.id).all()`. Furthermore, I've noticed that given a third table of type `A` with a relationship to `B`:

```
class C(A):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.a_id))
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(B.id))
    b = relationship(B, foreign_keys=[b_id])
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'c',
    }
```

If a query needs to join against that table `C`, e.g.:

```
session.query(B.id).join(C.b).filter(C.id == x).all()
```

the query will automatically join against both `C`'s underlying parent table and `B`'s underlying parent table (that's two joins against `A` in a single query that doesn't reference any of table `A`'s attributes), making the query needlessly verbose and complicated.

Is there any way to configure SQLAlchemy to join against polymorphic parent tables only when their attributes are needed? I've been unable to find anything about this use case in the documentation, but it's hard to believe that a library as flexible as SQLAlchemy would be limiting in this way.

Comment: Are you comfortable with querying using the core table underlying the mapped class? Since that'd do it.

Comment: that seems limiting because one use case is joining on table relationships. I should probably add that to the question to clarify what kind of behavior I'm looking for.